# Chrome History API bizarre behavior

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a simple chrome extension to delete a reddit url from my history every time I go to one and then replace it with a random wikipedia article. To do this I have a content script that passes a message to a background script to delete its url from the history:

content_script.js:

```
window.onload = chrome.runtime.sendMessage({greeting: "do the thing"});
```

background.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {

    console.log("deleting url " + sender.tab.url);
    //chrome.browsingData.removeCache({});

    chrome.history.deleteUrl( {url: sender.tab.url}, 
        function () {
            console.log("replacing url");
            chrome.history.addUrl({url: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random"});
        } 
    );
 });
```

All my console.log prints confirm that my script is executing correctly, no errors are thrown (even on the generated background page) but when I look at my history from `chrome://history` all the reddit urls I visited are still there, and there is just a single wikipedia visit at the top. ([image](http://imgur.com/JL4vuk3))

The bug is interesting because when I check the history using the chrome history API the reddit links aren't there! All that is printed is a single wikipedia link and my non-reddit history.

```
function printHistory(){
        chrome.history.search({text: '', maxResults: 10},

         function(data) {
            data.forEach(function(page) {
                console.log(page.url);
                });
        });
    }
```

So there are three problems

1. reddit urls aren't being deleted in chrome://history
2. wikipedia urls are only added once, at the end (or are somehow deleted and re-added each time).
3. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random isn't being resolved to an real link

Heres a git repo you can clone to reproduce the bug. https://github.com/rohanp/test

I have Chrome Version 44.0.2403.125 (64-bit)

Comment: @RobW turning off history sync solves problem 1! thanks!

Comment: As an aside: you shouldn't assign to `window.onload` in your content script.  The content script could run after the onload event, in which case nothing would happen.  In your case, you're executing the command `sendMessage` anyway and assigning the result (`null`?) to `window.onload`.  If you want to assign something to `window.onload`, you should assign a function (but not with a content script, since by default content scripts may not receive the event).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) reddit urls aren't being deleted in chrome://history

This is a [known bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=395955) due to History Sync not being affected by delete. It's unclear when it will be fixed.

> 2) wikipedia urls are only added once, at the end (or are somehow deleted and re-added each time)

That's just how History works - it only shows you the last visit to a particular page, hiding the previous ones.

> 3) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random isn't being resolved to an real link

And why would it? It's not like you're *really* visiting the page.

You should make an XHR request to [Wikipeida API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page) to [get a random page](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Random).

This should work, parse the result as JSON: `https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=random&rnnamespace=0&format=json`